# How do I capture print event in mac osx?

Tags: ios, macos, events, printing

Is there any system related Notification which fire on when we print any document or file on mac osx. or is there any way by which we can find out that any document on desktop or in files is being printed . a piece of code  or system command will be quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this looks like you should check it :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html